# Angular tour-of-heroes: no provider for HttpClient when testing a component

Tags: angular, angular-test

I've seen many threads about this error but in my case, I don't have any error with the `hero.service.spec.ts` (at least, nothing shows up) but I have the `No provider for HttpClient` when I test a component which depends on the `Hero` service (the `Hero` service depends on `HttpClient`, the component itself, no).

I get the same error with all the components which depend on `Hero` service.

[image: screenshot from Jasmine]

This is my `heroes.component.spec.ts`

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';

describe('HeroesComponent', () => {
  let component: HeroesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeroesComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeroesComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeroesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And my `hero.service.spec.ts`

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

describe('HeroService', () => {
  let service: HeroService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [HeroService]
    })
    service = TestBed.inject(HeroService)
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I'm new to Angular tests and this is quite annoying when you just try to run the `ng test` from the official tutorial and it doesn't work :-)

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `HttpClientTestingModule` in your component test's Angular testing module like so:

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';

describe('HeroesComponent', () => {
  let component: HeroesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeroesComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeroesComponent ],
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],  //  Add this line
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeroesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The `HeroesComponent` depends on the `HeroService` which depends on the `HttpClient`. Angular must be able to resolve all dependencies during runtime and tests.

During tests, we can break this dependency hierarchy at any point by providing a dependency with a test double.

For example, we could replace the `HeroService` with a fake object like so:

```js
const fakeHeroService = {
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of([]);
  }
};

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HeroesService,
      useValue: fakeHeroService,
    },
  ],
});
```

or we could replace the `HttpClient` with a test double like so (we rarely want to do this):

```js
const fakeHttpClient = {
  get(url, options): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of([]);
  }
};

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HttpClient,
      useValue: fakeHttpClient,
    },
  ],
});
```

The `HttpClient` has a lot of dependencies. `HttpClientTestingModule` provides fake versions of some of those dependencies and actual versions of other dependencies.

This Angular module also provides `HttpTestingController` which allows us to fake HTTP responses and set up expectations about the HTTP requests that were made during a tests.

It depends on what type of test you're writing and what you're trying to achieve. If you're doing an isolated unit test suite for `HeroesComponent`, you should replace all its direct dependencies with test doubles.

Here's an example of a stub that can replace the hero service.

```js
export const femaleMarvelHeroes: Hero[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Black Widow' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Captain Marvel' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Medusa' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Ms. Marvel' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Scarlet Witch' },
  { id: 6, name: 'She-Hulk' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Storm' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Wasp' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Rogue' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Elektra' },
  { id: 11, name: 'Gamora' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Hawkeye (Kate Bishop)' },
];

const heroServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj<HeroService>(
  HeroService.name,
  [
    'addHero',
    'deleteHero',
    'getHeroes',
  ]);
heroServiceStub.addHero
  .and.callFake(({ name }: Partial<Hero>) => observableOf({
    id: 42,
    name,
  }, asapScheduler))
  .calls.reset();
heroServiceStub .deleteHero
  .and.callFake((hero: Hero) => of(hero, asapScheduler))
  .calls.reset();
heroServiceStub .getHeroes
  .and.returnValue(of(femaleMarvelHeroes, asapScheduler))
  .calls.reset();
```

This snippet was extracted from my GitHub repository [LayZeeDK/ngx-tour-of-heroes-mvp](https://github.com/LayZeeDK/ngx-tour-of-heroes-mvp/blob/develop/src/app/heroes/heroes.container.spec.ts).

Learn more techniques for verifying collaborator integration in [Testing Angular container components](https://indepth.dev/testing-angular-container-components/).

Comment: it works! but I don't understand the logic: I thought TestBed was here to deal with DI. Here, this means I have to know how all services are implemented ? (I'm not supposed to know that this service depends on `HttpClient`). Anyway, thanks for the answer

Comment: I added an explanation. I hope it helps you get an understanding about what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import HttpClientTestingModule in your TestBed for heroes.component.spec.ts and provide HeroService as well.